# Output provides size of integer instead of the actual integer

Tags: c++

// Create classes called Class1 and Class2 with each having one private member. Add member function to set a value (say setValue) on each class. Add one more function max() that is friendly to both classes, max() function should compare two private member of two classes and show maximum among them. Create one-one object of each class and set a value on them. Display the maximum number among them

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Class1
{
    int a;

    public:
        int setValue();
    
    friend int max();
};

class Class2
{
    int b;

    public:
        int setValue();

    friend int max();
};

int Class1::setValue()
{
    cout<<"Enter the first number:";
    cin>>a;
}


int Class2::setValue()
{
    cout<<"Enter the second number:";
    cin>>b;
}

int max()
{
    Class1 c1;
    Class2 c2;

    if(c1.a>c2.b)
    {
        cout<<"Greater number: "<<c1.a<<endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout<<"Greater number: "<<c2.b<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Class1 obj1;
    Class2 obj2;

    obj1.setValue();
    obj2.setValue();
    cout<<endl;
    max();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `max` function creates two new objects and compares them. Is that what you want? Perhaps you want to pass the objects to compare as parameters to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared that `max` as well as both member functions `setValue`  return `int`. Those functions execute to the end without returning a value. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

Solution: Either return a value, or declare the function to return `void`.

---

Here:

> ```
> Class1 c1;
> Class2 c2;
> ```

You default initialise two variables. The members of those objects will be default initialised which in the case of `int` means that they have an indeterminate value.

On this line:

> ```
> if(c1.a>c2.b)
> ```

You compare indeterminate value to another indeterminate value. Same goes when outputting the greater value. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

Solution: Initialise all objects whose value you use. In this case, I suspect that you were supposed to not create new, uninitialised variables, but to read existing objects that were created in `main`. Typically, that is achieved by passing the values into the function as arguments.

Comment: it worked when i used void instead of int.

Answer (score 1):

I see some discrepancies in your code. First of all, what are you trying to return in `setValue()` method. You have made return type `int` instead of `void` into those `setValue()` method that is gonna give some error for sure. Into that friend function that finds for the maximum value also need to return an `int` as you have declared into the prototype of `max()`. I believe you should not return anything into from `setValue()` method.

---

Another this that you have done terribly wrong is:

```
Class1 c1;
Class2 c2;
```

Inside of `max` method, instead of passing the objects as arguments to the `max` method.
you have not passed the objects to the arguments of `max()` method. Creating a new objects of class1 and class2 inside of `max` method will not help. At the same time output will be undefined from `max` method.

---

Solution:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Class1
{
    int a;

    public:
        void setValue();
    
    friend int max(Class1 obj1, Class2 obj2);
};

class Class2
{
    int b;

    public:
        void setValue();

    friend int max(Class1 obj1, Class2 obj2);
};

void Class1::setValue()
{
    cout<<"Enter the first number:";
    cin>>a; // this sets the value of private data-member a.
}


void Class2::setValue()
{
    cout<<"Enter the second number:";
    cin>>b; // this sets the value of private data-member b.
}

int max(Class1 obj1, Class2 obj2)
{

    int max;


    if(obj1.a>=obj2.b)
    {
        cout<<"Greater number: "<<obj1.a<<endl;
        max=obj1.a;
    }

    else
    {
        cout<<"Greater number: "<<obj2.b<<endl;
        max=obj2.b;
    }
    return max;
}

int main()
{
    Class1 obj1;
    Class2 obj2;

    obj1.setValue();
    obj2.setValue();
    cout<<endl;
    int maximum=max(obj1, obj2);
    cout<<"Maximum is: "<< maximum<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Hope, this will help. :-)

Comment: I was trying to learn to use objects as arguments! thank you tho

Comment: @SibindraTimalsina, you can pass the objects as arguments like the way I have passed into the `max ` method.  For more info: go through 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/passing-and-returning-objects-in-c/

Comment: @SibindraTimalsina accept this answer, if it has solved your problem. So it will help others to find the right answer of same type of question.

Answer (score 0):

You should try passing the `Class1` and `Class2` objects you want to compare instead of creating new local `Class1` and `Class2` objects inside of the `max` function.

Try something like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Class1;
class Class2;

class Class1
{
    int a;

    public:
        void setValue();
    
    friend int max(Class1 c1, Class2 c2);
};

class Class2
{
    int b;

    public:
        void setValue();

    friend int max(Class1 c1, Class2 c2);
};

void Class1::setValue()
{
    cout<<"Enter the first number:";
    cin>>a;
}


void Class2::setValue()
{
    cout<<"Enter the second number:";
    cin>>b;
}

int max(Class1 c1, Class2 c2)
{
    int maxValue;
    
    if(c1.a>c2.b)
    {
        cout<<"Greater number: "<<c1.a<<endl;
        maxValue = c1.a;
    }

    else
    {
        cout<<"Greater number: "<<c2.b<<endl;
        maxValue = c2.b;
    }

    return maxValue;
}

int main()
{
    Class1 obj1;
    Class2 obj2;

    obj1.setValue();
    obj2.setValue();
    cout<<endl;
    int maxValue = max(obj1, obj2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just curious why this answer was downvoted? Feedback is appreciated so that I don't repeat the same mistakes again.

Comment: I guess because `int max` is a function that claims to return `int` but doesn't have a return path. In the op's code, their `setValue` functions share this issue - might be worth pointing out so the answer is complete (although the second point isn't worth downvoting over imo).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback George, that makes sense. I can see how pointing out those issues could add to the answer. Since another answer already points this out, I'm not going to try to repeat the same thing. I have modified the snippet in my answer to make it more complete and hopefully better address the original question posted by the OP.

Comment: I also see a few other things with the OP's snippet that I would recommend changing, like why have a function, `max`, that not only calculates the maximum value, but also performs the action of printing the maximum value. There could be better separation of concerns there. I'm also not sure what the point of using two different classes with a friend function instead of just using a single class with maybe an overloaded comparison operator or a max static method that takes 2 instances of the same class. Not sure if that would be appropriate to also point out?

Comment: I'm new trying to answer questions on this site, and still learning.

Comment: That's down to discretion really. I would argue in this case, it's worth pointing to things the op could do differently with their code, as they're a beginner. But it's not practical a lot of the time to go in depth on all the mistakes in a question's code. In terms of answer guidelines - answering only the question the op asked is enough. Including only legal code in an answer also scores some brownie points. Anyway, answer looks more or less good to me so I've upvoted. (Although I'd still like to see the setters changed to `void` - even if not mentioned in the answer :))